# Magento 2.3.2 Import only images for multiple products

Tags: magento2, product-import

I want to import images for multiple products. I read many questions and I tried the answer but with no luck.

I want to import images from external server. For that I created CSV with `sku, base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image` column.

The value in all field is like :
htts://external.com/imgae_name

I selected "Product" in Entity Type, Import Behaviour is Add/ Update. I skip Image file directory.

When I click on "check data" button I am getting following error.

> Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 1

If I add Product type column then I am getting attribute set error. Can anybody help me on that ?

Even when I import custom attribute I am getting same error. For that I created csv with sku and cost.

Here cost is my product attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs while adding product images "Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 1" is because the sku on first row you are trying to add image does not exist in the magento system or maybe system does not find the image on the specified url.

Comment: Thanks. Yes on csv one sku was wrong. But other issue, I am getting following error now :
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.

Comment: I don't think you should add a url_key column while importing images.